# Redirect url if checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problem with redirecting urls after checkboxes are selected. I am using document.location for this, but this doesn´t work in my code. I'm trying to fix it, but without success.

This is the part of my code which doesn't work:

```
function objednat() {
    var adress = "";
    if (document.getelementbyid('BoxtarifVolani1').checked == true) {
        adress += "#tarifVolani1";
    }
    window.location = 'http://www.investcon.webinpage.cz/cz/objednat-tarif-dobijeci-cislo/' + adresa;
}
```

I want to redirect this to a form, which will be filled with the selected values. I don't know why, but this document.location doesn't work in the code.

This is the part of the code I use in the formula for grabbing the hash from the url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if(window.location.hash) {

 //set the value as a variable, and remove the #
 var hash_value = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');

 if (tarifVolani1 == true) { 
 document.getelementbyid('BoxtarifVolani1").checked = true;}
 ....
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `getelementbyid` should be `getElementById` . Javascript is case-sensitive. Also, `adresa` should be `adress`.. And you have another syntax error here: `getelementbyid('BoxtarifVolani1")` which should be `getElementById('BoxtarfiVolani1')`. Moreover, you apparently are not using jQuery.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Taking the effort to use proper language and grammar would make me more inclined to help. You not taking the time to spell out "you" causes me to not having the time to help you.

Comment: Im sorry for my grammar, i know is not the best.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you have done is right, except, the function name is wrong case:

1. Change `getelementbyid` to `getElementById`.
2. Change `adresa` to `adress`.

**Code:**

```
function objednat() {
    var adress = "";
    if (document.getElementById('BoxtarifVolani1').checked == true) {
        adress += "#tarifVolani1";
    }
    window.location = 'http://www.investcon.webinpage.cz/cz/objednat-tarif-dobijeci-cislo/' + adress;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery way of doing it

```
function objednat() {
    var adress = "";
    if ($('#BoxtarifVolani1').is(':checked')) {
        adress += "#tarifVolani1";
    }
    window.location = 'http://www.investcon.webinpage.cz/cz/objednat-tarif-dobijeci-cislo/'+adress;
}
```

For your ref: [jQuery :checked Selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)